# Using .net Core 3.0 in an app service container doesn't actually run 3.0

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an app service instance that I would like to run .net core 3.0 in. I selected 3.0 in the stack settings (which is new as of perhaps a day or two ago). (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhCkp.png)

But when the instance spins up 3.0 is not available as a runtime on the newly created instance:

```
# dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Obviously this isn't going to run a .net 3.0 app.

I tried to change the .net stack I've picked to see the reaction I'd get from the instance that got spun up. In all cases except when selecting 3.0 I was seeing the correct version of .net both in the list-runtimes as well as the banner that's printed out upon login via SSH.

```
Last login: Fri Oct  4 15:07:51 2019 from 172.16.1.2
  _____
  /  _  \ __________ _________   ____
 /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \
/    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/
\____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
        \/      \/                  \/
A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X

Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
Dotnet quickstart: https://aka.ms/dotnet-qs
.NETCore runtime version: 2.2.6
```

The runtime version on the banner matches the selected version in all cases *except* when choosing 3.0.

I expected that when I chose a .net core 3.0 stack that I would get an instance that supported 3.0, but in reality it seems that it only came with 2.2 installed.

---

Edit: It looks like the feature was only partially rolled out in that it allowed *selecting* 3.0 but it did *not* have a VM that supported it yet. As of this morning it seems to all be finally working.

Comment: Where you create this azure function? seems like on my portal. the .net core 3.0 can not be selected.

Comment: Wasn't a function, was an app service. But regardless, I'm now able to both select 3.0 and actually *get* a 3.0 container as well.

Comment: I made a mistake. but when I created the App Service, there was really no 3.0 option.

Answer (score 0):

Now, .Net Core 3.0 is [not support in Azure App Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISIcj.png).

On my portal seems can't choose stack of .net core 3.0, but you can have a try on this way:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After accept the legal terms, select 'OK'.

This solution comes from [the offical doc of .net core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#deploy-aspnet-core-30-to-azure-app-service). And it tells you how to deploy .net core 3.0 to Azure App Service until .net core 3.0 is available on Azure App Service.

Comment: Which is weird because on my Azure portal it is in the dropdown: https://i.imgur.com/4fw4Uwm.png . 

Likewise, my extensions button is disabled as well.